# Scala implicit conversion to monadic value within effectful macro

Tags: scala, dsl, implicit

**Edit:** I updated the question to be more descriptive.

**Note:** I use the Scala 2.11 compiler, because that is the compiler version used by the LMS tutorial project.

I am porting a DSL written in Haskell to Scala. The DSL is an imperative language, so I used monads with do-notation, namely `WriterT [Stmt] (State Label) a`. I had trouble porting this to Scala, but worked around it by using the `ReaderWriterState` monad and just using Unit for the `Reader` component. I then went about searching for an alternative for the do-notation found in Haskell. For-comprehensions are supposed to be this alternative in Scala, but they are tailored towards sequences, I e.g. could not pattern match a tuple, it would insert a call to `filter`. So I started looking for alternatives and found multiple libraries: `effectful`, `monadless`, and `each`. I tried `effectful` first which does exactly what I wanted to achieve, I even prefer it over Haskell's do-notation, and it worked well with the `ReaderWriterState` monad from `ScalaZ` I had been using. In my DSL I have actions like `Drop()` (a case class) that I want to be able to use directly as a statement. I hoped to use implicits for this, but because the `!` method of `effectful` (or `monadless` equivalent for that matter) is too general, I cannot get Scala to automatically convert my `Action` case classes to something of type `Stmt` (the `ReaderWriterState` that returns `Unit`).

So if not implicits, would there be a different way to achieve it?

As shown in `Main.passes2`, I did figure out a workaround that I would not mind using, but I am curious whether I stumbled upon is some limitation of the language, or is simply my lack of experience with Scala.

With `Main.fails1` I will get the following error message: Implicit not found: `scalaz.Unapply[scalaz.Monad, question.Label]`. Unable to unapply type `question.Label` into atype constructor of kind `M[_]` that is classified by the type class `scalaz.Monad`. Check that the type class is defined by compiling `implicitly[scalaz.Monad[type constructor]]` and review the implicits in object `Unapply`, which only cover common type 'shapes.'

Which comes from ScalaZ its `Unapply`: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/d2aba553e444f951adc847582226d617abae24da/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Unapply.scala#L50

And with `Main.fails2` I will just get: value `!` is not a member of `question.Label`

I assume it is just a matter of writing the missing implicit definition, but I am not quite sure which one Scala wants me to write.

The most important bits of my build.sbt are the version:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.2",
```

And the dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.11.2",
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.11.2",
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.11.2",
libraryDependencies += "org.pelotom" %% "effectful" % "1.0.1",
```

Here is the relevant code, containing the things I tried and the code necessary to run those things:

```
package question

import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

import effectful._

object DSL {
  type GotoLabel = Int
  type Expr[A] = ReaderWriterState[Unit, List[Action], GotoLabel, A]
  type Stmt = Expr[Unit]

  def runStmt(stmt: Stmt, startLabel: GotoLabel): (Action, GotoLabel) = {
    val (actions, _, updatedLabel) = stmt.run(Unit, startLabel)
    val action = actions match {
      case List(action) => action
      case _ => Seq(actions)
    }
    (action, updatedLabel)
  }

  def runStmt(stmt: Stmt): Action = runStmt(stmt, 0)._1

  def getLabel(): Expr[GotoLabel] =
    ReaderWriterState((_, label) => (Nil, label, label))

  def setLabel(label: GotoLabel): Stmt =
    ReaderWriterState((_, _) => (Nil, Unit, label))

  implicit def actionStmt(action: Action): Stmt =
    ReaderWriterState((_, label) => (List(action), Unit, label))
}

import DSL._

final case class Label(label: String) extends Action
final case class Goto(label: String) extends Action
final case class Seq(seq: List[Action]) extends Action
sealed trait Action {
  def stmt(): Stmt = this
}

object Main {
  def freshLabel(): Expr[String] = effectfully {
    val label = getLabel.! + 1
    setLabel(label).!
    s"ants-$label"
  }

  def passes0() =
    freshLabel()
      .flatMap(before => Label(before))
      .flatMap(_ => freshLabel())
      .flatMap(after => Label(after));

  def passes1() = effectfully {
    unwrap(actionStmt(Label(unwrap(freshLabel()))))
    unwrap(actionStmt(Label(unwrap(freshLabel()))))
  }

  def fails1() = effectfully {
    unwrap(Label(unwrap(freshLabel())))
    unwrap(Label(unwrap(freshLabel())))
  }

  def pasess2() = effectfully {
    Label(freshLabel.!).stmt.!
    Label(freshLabel.!).stmt.!
  }

  def fails2() = effectfully {
    Label(freshLabel.!).!
    Label(freshLabel.!).!
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    runStmt(passes0())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Question quality***

I want to start with complaining about the question quality. You provide almost no textual description of what you are trying to achieve and then just show us a wall of code but don't explicitly reference your dependencies. This is far from what could count as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And typically you get much more chances to get some answers if you provide a clear problem that is easy to understand and reproduce.

***Back to the business***

When you write something like

```
unwrap(Label(unwrap(freshLabel())))
```

you ask too much from the Scala compiler. Particularly `unwrap` can unwrap only something that is wrapped into some `Monad`, but `Label` is not a monad. It is not just the fact that there is no `Monad[Label]` instance, it is the fact that it structurally doesn't fit that kills you. Simply speaking an instance of ScalaZ `Unapply` is an object that allows you to split an applied generic type `MonadType[SpecificType]` (or other `FunctorType[SpecificType]`) into  an "unapplied"/"partially-applied" `MonadType[_]` and `SpecificType` even when (as in your case) `MonadType[_]` is actually something complicated like `ReaderWriterState[Unit, List[Action], GotoLabel, _]`. And so the error says that there is no known way to split `Label` into some `MonadType[_]` and `SpecifictType`. You probably expected that your `implicit` `actionStmt` would do the trick to auto-convert `Label` into a `Statement` but this step is too much for the Scala compiler because for it to work, it also implies splitting the composite type. Note that this conversion is far from obvious for the compiler as the `unwrap` is itself a generic method that can handle any `Monad`. Actually in some sense ScalaZ needs `Unapply` exactly because the compiler can't do such things automatically. Still if you help the compiler just a little bit by specifying generic type, it can do the rest of the work:

```
def fails1() = effectfully {
  // fails
  // unwrap(Label(unwrap(freshLabel()))) 
  // unwrap(Label(unwrap(freshLabel())))

  // works
  unwrap[Stmt](Label(unwrap(freshLabel())))
  unwrap[Stmt](Label(unwrap(freshLabel())))
}
```

There is also another possible solution but it is a quite dirty hack: you can roll out your custom `Unapply` to persuade the compiler that `Label` is actually the same as `Expr[Unit]` which can be split as `Expr[_]` and `Unit`:

```
  implicit def unapplyAction[AC <: Action](implicit TC0: Monad[Expr]): Unapply[Monad, AC] {
    type M[X] = Expr[X]
    type A = Unit
  } = new Unapply[Monad, AC] {
    override type M[X] = Expr[X]
    override type A = Unit

    override def TC: Monad[Expr] = TC0

    // This can't be implemented because Leibniz really witness only exactly the same types rather than some kind of isomorphism
    // Luckily effectful doesn't use leibniz implementation         
    override def leibniz: AC === Expr[Unit] = ???
  }
```

The obvious reason why this is a dirty hack is that `Label` is actually not the same as `Expr[Unit]` and you can see it by the fact that you can't implement `leibniz` in your `Unapply`. Anyway, if you import `unapplyAction`, even your original `fails1` will compile and work because effectful doesn't use `leibniz` inside.

As for your `fails2`, I don't think you can make it work in any simple way. Probably the only way that you may try is to create another macro that would convert in-place call to `!` on your `action` (or its implicit wrapper) into the `effectful`'s `!` on the `action.stmt`. This might work but I didn't try it.

Comment: I find your first comment about the question quality rather unfair, considering the fact that I went into the effort of exactly trying to do what you complain about. Limiting the code size, but still provide enough to provide some context. And about the textual description, I ask about the problem, I refer to a specific code snippet, no point in providing that in text as well. Granted, I show what I tried to do not textually but through the code, but I expected that to be more clear. I was doubting whether I should have supplied a build.sbt, but hoped my imports where clear enough.

Comment: That aside, thank you for you thorough answer! Especially the unapply definition is helpful in understanding how I should go about doing so. Considering my goal was to reduce the syntactic noise, I will probably try your third approach and see whether I can make my own macro that calls the other macro.

Comment: @OttidMes, the part about the question might be not fair but I shared the experience I had while I tried to answer it. And I think the lack of other answers before mine is a sign that your question is far from perfect. I still strongly believe that a text description of your intentions is a **_must_** for any non-trivial question because I believe that "_[It’s harder to read code than to write it.](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/)_".

Comment: As for set up, it took me like 30 minutes to get it. Unlike `ScalaZ`, `effectful` is not a very popular library. So first I googled for it and the only version I've found was not updated for ages: it seems to not work witch Scala 2.12 or new versions of `ScalaZ`. So finally I had to set up a new project from scratch just for your question instead of re-using my existing SO-designated-project (as I think many do). And to me it looks like I was the only one determined enough to go through all that.

Comment: I am sorry for the trouble I caused you in answering my question. Next time I will make sure to also supply a build.sbt file, that is made just for the question, if there are any imports involved. Like I said, I am new to Scala, and was unaware that it would break on newer versions of the Scala compiler. Might I suggest you ask this in a comment to the question next time, instead of having me waste your time, while I would have been happy to have supplied a build.sbt.

Comment: I could have supplied a little more text description, but I thought I made my intentions clear with my very first sentence, I wanted to write a DSL with a certain syntax as shown in the code. But because you stress this so much, once I have managed to implement the macro, I will update the question to make it a bit more descriptive. About your quote, I find those quotes almost always to be worthless, they are too generalized to be of any use. It will always depend on the situation.

Comment: I already know of the linked article, and I do not really see how it applies here. I provided examples of what I tried, what I wanted to achieve, and when it went wrong, together with the code necessary to make those examples work, nothing more.

Comment: In the future I will make sure to make my question description stand on its own, without the support of any code. And I will make sure my code can be tested more easily. And I hope you will ask others of this in the form of a comment, not after the fact. That way you would not have to go through the effort you went through, others might have answered as well, and I would have been happy to have supplied it, instead of feeling both annoyed and happy with your answer. But this aside, I applaud your for your determination and thank you for the effort it providing me with a well thought out answer